# TransformerExeption when creating XML file

Tags: java, xml, file, parsing, dom

I'm making a Java quiz program. I need a way to save a question to an XML file. So my QuestionSaver class needs a Question and saves it to an XML file. Generating the Document goes fine but I get an TransformerException. There must be something wrong with the way I generate my document, but I don't know what.

Here is a part of my code:

```
/**
 * Default constructor for the QuestionSaver
 */
public QuestionSaver(){

}

public void saveQuestion(Question question) throws ParserConfigurationException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    // create the quiz root element
    Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
    Element rootElement = doc.createElement("question");
    doc.appendChild(rootElement);

    save(rootElement, doc, question);
}

/**
 * General method for saving the question to the xml file
 */
private void save(Element rootElement, Document doc, Question question) {
    /* first, save the question type independent properties */
    SaveIndependentProperties(rootElement, doc, question);

    /* Save the generated Document to an XML file */
    try {
        SaveToFile(doc);
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Saves the created document to an XML file
 * 
 * @throws TransformerConfigurationException
 */
private void SaveToFile(Document doc) throws TransformerConfigurationException {
    try {
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        // StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\file.xml"));

        // Output to console for testing
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

        transformer.transform(source, result);
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        System.out.println("TransformerException got thrown!");
    }

    System.out.println("File saved!");

}

/**
 * Saves the properties of a question, which are independent from the questiontype
 * 
 * @param rootElement
 */
private void SaveIndependentProperties(Element rootElement, Document doc, Question question) {
    /* add the actual question */
    Element actualquestion = doc.createElement("actualquestion");
    actualquestion.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(question.getQuestion()));
    rootElement.appendChild(actualquestion);

    /* add the score */
    Element score = doc.createElement("score");
    score.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(Integer.toString(question.getScore())));
    rootElement.appendChild(score);

    /* add the type */
    QuestionType questionType = question.getType();
    Element type = doc.createElement("type");
    type.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(getQuestionTypeString(questionType)));
    rootElement.appendChild(type);

    /* add the source */
    Element source = doc.createElement("source");
    source.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(question.getSource()));
    rootElement.appendChild(source);

    /* add the extra information */
    Element extraInformation = doc.createElement("extrainformation");
    extraInformation.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(question.getExtraInformation()));
    rootElement.appendChild(extraInformation);

}

/**
 * Converts a QuestionType to a string representing the QuestionType
 * 
 * @param questionType the QuestionType
 * @return
 */
private String getQuestionTypeString(QuestionType questionType) {
    if (questionType == QuestionType.MULTIPLEANSWER)
        return "multipleanswer";
    else if (questionType == QuestionType.MULTIPLECHOICE)
        return "multiplechoice";
    else
        return "speed";
}

     static void main(String args[]) {
      try {
        new QuestionSaver().saveQuestion(question);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your code somewhat and tried it out. To me it works.
Something to keep in mind:
You started the saving process inside the constructor of your class. This is most probably the cause of your trouble. Doing a saving step inside the constructor is almose always against best java practice. In my class the whole thing is stateless, meaning you can use the same instance of QuestionSaver at different points in your code without having a problem. Look at the how the code is executed inside the main method at the end of the file.

```
public class QuestionSaver {

    /**
     * Public constructor for the QuestionSaver
     * 
     * @param question the question to be saved
     * @throws ParserConfigurationException
     */
    public QuestionSaver(){

    }

    public void saveQuestion(Question question) throws ParserConfigurationException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        // create the quiz root element
        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        Element rootElement = doc.createElement("question");
        doc.appendChild(rootElement);

        save(rootElement, doc, question);
    }

    /**
     * General method for saving the question to the xml file
     */
    private void save(Element rootElement, Document doc, Question question) {
        /* first, save the question type independent properties */
        SaveIndependentProperties(rootElement, doc, question);

        /* Save the generated Document to an XML file */
        try {
            SaveToFile(doc);
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Saves the created document to an XML file
     * 
     * @throws TransformerConfigurationException
     */
    private void SaveToFile(Document doc) throws TransformerConfigurationException {
        try {
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            // StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\file.xml"));

            // Output to console for testing
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

            transformer.transform(source, result);
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            System.out.println("Fout met transformen!");
        }

        System.out.println("File saved!");

    }

    /**
     * Saves the properties of a question, which are independent from the questiontype
     * 
     * @param rootElement
     */
    private void SaveIndependentProperties(Element rootElement, Document doc, Question question) {
        /* add the actual question */
        Element actualquestion = doc.createElement("actualquestion");
        actualquestion.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(question.getQuestion()));
        rootElement.appendChild(actualquestion);

        /* add the score */
        Element score = doc.createElement("score");
        score.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(Integer.toString(question.getScore())));
        rootElement.appendChild(score);

        /* add the type */
        QuestionType questionType = question.getType();
        Element type = doc.createElement("type");
        type.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(getQuestionTypeString(questionType)));
        rootElement.appendChild(type);

        /* add the source */
        Element source = doc.createElement("source");
        source.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(question.getSource()));
        rootElement.appendChild(source);

        /* add the extra information */
        Element extraInformation = doc.createElement("extrainformation");
        extraInformation.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(question.getExtraInformation()));
        rootElement.appendChild(extraInformation);

    }

    /**
     * Converts a QuestionType to a string representing the QuestionType
     * 
     * @param questionType the QuestionType
     * @return
     */
    private String getQuestionTypeString(QuestionType questionType) {
        if (questionType == QuestionType.MULTIPLEANSWER)
            return "multipleanswer";
        else if (questionType == QuestionType.MULTIPLECHOICE)
            return "multiplechoice";
        else
            return "speed";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new QuestionSaver().saveQuestion(new Question());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: The exception gets thrown in the SaveToFile method.When I print the stack trace I get this: [basic links](http://imgur.com/652vJY9)

Comment: Thanks for the advice about the stateless design! The errors are gone, but the TransformerException still gets thrown at the end of the SaveToFile method. My output is now: "ERROR:  ''
TransformerException got thrown!
File saved!"          I updated my code to yours btw.    Thanks in advance!

Comment: Plz edit your post with the current code and a copy of maybe the last 10 lines of your stack trace. Probably its some problem of data conversion. Do you have any of your values inside the Question set to null? If so, that is your problem...

Comment: Then write inside saveIndependentProperties:
`actualquestion.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(question.getQuestion()  == null ? "" : question.getQuestion()));` istead. Like that you prevent the null pointers from happening.

Comment: Thank you for your response. If there is nothing wrong witht the code I provided, there must be something wrong with the QuetionParser and something in the Question must be null. The stack trace says something about NUllpointerException so I it must be that!